# How to add a Keycloak Identity Provider extension for Discord onto a docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, discord, keycloak, keycloak-services

I have a docker compose of keycloak that looks like this:

```
  keycloak:
    container_name: keycloak
    image: jboss/keycloak:16.1.1
    environment:
      DB_VENDOR: postgres
      DB_ADDR: postgres
      DB_PORT: temp
      # Database name (replace with yours)
      DB_DATABASE: temp
      # Database user (replace with yours)
      DB_USER: temp
      # Database password (replace with yours)
      DB_PASSWORD: temp
      # Keycloak user (replace with yours)
      KEYCLOAK_USER: temp
      # Keycloak password (replace with yours)
      KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: temp
      JGROUPS_DISCOVERY_PROTOCOL: JDBC_PING
      JGROUPS_DISCOVERY_PROPERTIES: datasource_jndi_name=java:jboss/datasources/KeycloakDS,info_writer_sleep_time=500,initialize_sql="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS JGROUPSPING ( own_addr varchar(200) NOT NULL, cluster_name varchar(200) NOT NULL, created timestamp default current_timestamp, ping_data BYTEA, constraint PK_JGROUPSPING PRIMARY KEY (own_addr, cluster_name))"
      PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING: 'true'
      KEYCLOAK_LOGLEVEL: WARN
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:8080/"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 3
      start_period: 120s
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      # Keycloak URL (replace with yours)
      - "traefik.http.routers.keycloak.rule=Host(`domain`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.keycloak.service=keycloak"
      - "traefik.http.routers.keycloak.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.services.keycloak.loadbalancer.server.port=8080"
      - "traefik.http.routers.keycloak.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.keycloak.tls.certresolver=dockerssl"
      - "traefik.http.services.keycloak.loadbalancer.passhostheader=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.keycloak.middlewares=compresstraefik"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.compresstraefik.compress=true"
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      keycloak-postgres:
        condition: service_healthy
```

There is another image with the postgres info but I don't think I need to show that here. Overall it runs great on the VPS that it was put into, I have gotten the page up and everything in the base keycloak works. I use a CICD from Github so any push requests I do on the github to the main branch are immediately sent to the VPS.

Now what I want to do is add the functionality of these two repositories:

https://github.com/wadahiro/keycloak-discord ,
https://github.com/kywan/keycloak-discord-roles-sync

Basically using the discord server as a point of reference for giving roles on various internal sites used by management.

How can I implement the .jar files from both the discord repositories inside the github repository so if I switched to another server I wouldn't have to manually reinstall the files. Is there a way through the github workflow or the docker-compose.yml?

Sorry if this came off noobish I am new to docker and keycloak. If there is anything you want to correct me on I am always open to criticsm. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

I am setting up keycloak myself and what I did to make the discord oauth provider (https://github.com/wadahiro/keycloak-discord) avilable is to download the .jar and mount a local volume `providers` to the docker container e.g. `-v $PWD/providers:/opt/keycloak/providers` or in a docker-compose it would look like

```
keycloak:
    container_name: keycloak
    image: jboss/keycloak:16.1.1
    volumes:
      - $PWD/providers:/opt/keycloak/providers
[...]
```

Here are my steps so far
https://hackmd.io/@tPxwddC0R3uDaZSGNlIInA/r1VAnz9Rc#Start-the-container-as-developer-environment

Did I get it right that you would like to have it *in* your docker container to have it always available?

In that case if you are the owner of `jboss/keycloak:16.1.1` you would need to put the .jar files in `/opt/keycloak/providers` while you build the container